# Azure Devops install helm chart to local kubernetes cluster in pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to create a task in an azure devops pipeline to install a helm chart to a local kubernetes cluster?

I have been able to package the chart in the pipeline using...

```
        helm package ./<projectname>/yaml/helm/sample-app
```

I would imagine something similar to this would work (this does not work currently)

```
- task: HelmDeploy@0
            inputs:
              connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
              kubernetesServiceConnection: 'myk8sserviceconnection'
              namespace: 'staging'
              command: 'upgrade'
              chartType: 'FilePath'
              chartPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/sample-app
```

When I try this it warns that I'm missing properties...

[image]

Azure devops is deployed locally v2020 update 1.1

I dont want to deploy to azure or use an azure container registry, I just want to take the helm chart in the repo, package it and install it in my cluster.

I have access to my kubernetes cluster using a service connection in devops, I am able to deploy to kubernetes using @KubernetesManifest@0 task.

*** UPDATE see answer below ***

Comment: Did you try ignoring those? Afaik, they are not required.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I didnt realize these values were not required. I'll update my question with the final code, in case someone else struggles through the documentation.

Comment: @pforsthoff better is just post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion, these values are not required. Here is my final pipeline stage that's working well:

```
- task: HelmDeploy@0
      inputs:
        connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
        kubernetesServiceConnection: 'myk8sserviceconnection'
        namespace: 'staging'
        command: 'upgrade'
        chartType: FilePath
        chartPath: ./sample-app/yaml/helm/sample-app
        releaseName: sample-app
        install: true
        waitForExecution: false
```